# jquery Client Side validation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am trying to validater my .aspx form using jQuery Validate plugin. I have written the function for the validation with the rules for checking and messages for showing the error messages.

But even after adding all the necessary plugins and function calls, my form is not getting validated.

Can anyone please guide me if am wrong somewhere.

I am attaching the .aspx code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

            //$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
                debugger;
                $("#form1").validate({


                    rules: {
                        lblName: "required",
                        lblCity: "required",
                        lblDepName: "required",
                        lblSalary: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true
                        },

                    },

                    // Specify the validation error messages
                    messages: {
                        lblName: "Please enter your Name",
                        lblCity: "Please enter your City",
                        lblDepName: "Please select a department Name from the dropdown list",
                        lblSalary: {
                            required: "Please enter the Salary",
                            number: "Only Numbers are allowed"
                        }
                    },

                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                });
                $('#btnInsertEmployee').click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    if ($("#form1").validate()) {

                    }
                });
            //});
        });


    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 146px;
            height: 26px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 26px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">


                </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <br />
                <br />
&nbsp;
                <table class="auto-style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style3">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text="City"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDepName" runat="server" Text="Department Name"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="16px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDepName_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="122px">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSalary" runat="server" Text="Salary"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnInsertEmployee" runat="server" OnClick="btnInsertEmployee_Click" Text="Insert Employee"  />
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be your script tag path isn't resolved yet trying replacing `Scripts/` with `~/Scripts/` and run again.

Comment: <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> both are same you should use any one here sample code : http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ZrfhU/

Comment: Thank you. But still am getting some error.

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined I am getting even though I have added the Jquery plugin first and mentioned with ~/ prefixed.

Comment: That means jQuery isn't being loaded, aka "Scripts" isn't where it's located on your web server.  You'll have to fix that before any other issues.  Once you get that sorted out, read the [FAQ for jQuery Validate](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lblName or lblCity, it should be txtName or txtCity.

```
rules: {
            txtName: "required",
            txtCity: "required",
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
           txtName: "Please enter your Name",
           txtCity: "Please enter your City",
        },
```